# Facebook SDK for Unity for Android: a lot of trash in .unitypackage

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I'm trying to integrate Facebook into mobile cross platform game created with Unity. So I download latest SDK for Unity (v6.0 - August 11, 2014). After importing .unitypackage I've got **1386 files** in `Assets/Plugins/Android/facebook/` folder (including `.meta` files for version control) and some files in other directories. Looks like the whole Eclipse project was just dumped with all sources (`.java` files), generated files (`gen/` folder), and intermediate derivatives (`.class` files). How comes that `.jar` file is not enough? Is all this stuff really required for proper functioning? What can be safely deleted?

Why has importing the package overwritten my AndroidManifest.xml? It contained a lot of actually required settings.

Thank you for considering my questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posted [report](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/777106495684130/), which was probably misuse of  Facebook bug tracker, sorry for that. But this succeeded, thanks to Tushar Arora for response! The answer was: “Deleting the project will not affect your app. You only need the jar file to make your unity app.”

> We ship everything (including eclipse project) as a package because some developers prefer seeing what the jar file consists of and how it works.

I'd suggest delivering source project in a separate download; or at least as single archive file inside `.unitypackage`. So we could simply uncheck one file while importing, since it should not pollute Unity project working directory anyway.